Why does int.__class__ give type in Python?
From what I've read, the built-in types such as int, float, dict, etc have been implemented in C, and they used to be different from user-defined classes before Python 2.2
However, the built-in types and user defined classes have long been unified now, and the following happens
>>> int.__class__
<class 'type'>

Why does this happen? I'm aware that type is a metaclass in Python, and all the user defined classes (by default) are (meta) instances of the same, and it gives me the impression that any object that is an instance of type has been instantiated using the type metaclass.
But built-in classes, such as int, have been implemented in C, and haven't been created using the type metaclass, right? Then, why does int.__class__, for example, give <class 'type'>?
Is it that, "manually", the __class__ attribute of built-in types such as int, has been set to type, to enable the unification?

Just because it's implemented in C doesn't mean it can't "fake" the same class hierarchy…!?

@deceze Yeah, so the last sentence of the question is (at least, somewhat) correct? It just seemed strange to me, this is the first time I'm dealing with OOP. And I suppose I can extend the "faking" to type(type) being type as well?

"Fake" isn't really an accurate description of what's going on. class defines a type by ultimately invoking a metaclass. For the built-in types, whatever invoking a metaclass does is simply done directly.

@chepner Does the invoking thing apply to, say, type(type) being type? Does the metaclass...invoke itself? And object is an instance of type, so if it invokes type, how does that happen, given that type itself inherits from object?

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but here are a few comments. type(type) doesn't create anything; type.__call__ is just overloaded to return the __class__ attribute of a single argument. The three-argument form is how you actually create a new instance of type, but part of what it does is first get a new object from object.__new__, then configure it properly to be a type.

@chepner Ah, I didn't frame my question well, sorry. You stated that for the built-in types, whatever is done when a metaclass is invoked to create a user-defined class, is done directly. This is rationale for type(int) == type, right? Does that rationale hold for type(type) == type? The __class__ of type is "manually" set to be type, just for the sake of consistency, right? I hope I'm making some sense here.

Yes, the implementation is responsible for ensuring that type.__class__ gets set to type after type has been defined.

Classes created in C are still classes and share the same core structure in memory as classes created in pure Python code. The same mechanisms used from Python to create a class can be used to create a class from C code. The only thing is that they don't "have to": a class in C can have all its inner fields hard coded, and its class members manually assigned: unlike Python code there are no guards for assigning the __class__ field of the class object.
As I said: regardless of that, these built-in classes are still "real" instances of type, as the memory layout to the special slots, both public and private have the layout used by type.
And - on top of all that - even for Python defined classes, it is possible to change the __class__ attribute of a class (but with restrictions).
yes, as simple as that: just assign a new value to the __class__ attribute of an existing instance. This will effectivelly "transform" an object into another, carrying its instance namespace. It is not the same thing as cast does in static typed languages: with cast in Java/C++ an object is unchanged, and the compiler just tried to apply the next operation as if the casted instance where from the cast-target class. Assigning to __class__ is a permanent change (until a reassignment, of course) to the underlying instance:
See this in action:
In [51]: class A:
    ...:     def a(self):
    ...:         ...
    ...: 

In [52]: class B:
    ...:     def b(self):
    ...:         print("at method B")
    ...: 

In [53]: a = A()

In [54]: a.__class__ = B

In [55]: a.b()
at method B


It won't work if both classes have diffing "memory layouts" - that is, data structures defined in native code, such as lists or tuples, or using the __slots__ mechanism. But for "ordinary" classes which keep the instance namespace in the __dict__ attribute, it just works.

Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit on the last paragraph (or provide sources for further reading)?

Sure - there it is.
